# Is there a way to broadcast boolean masks?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to reduce the number of calculations I do based on search distance.  I have N nodes and an `[NxN]` boolean mask that tells me what nodes are within X distance of the other nodes with `T` true values.

I also have `[Nx(d)]` data for each node, where `(d)` can be `(1)`, `(3)`, or `(3x3)`. I want the "sparse" format which is a `[Tx(d)]` array so I can do vectorized calculations along the 0 axis. Right now I do this:

`sparseData=data.repeat(data.shape[0],axis=0).reshape(np.concatenate(([data.shape[0],data.shape])))[mask]`

Which works, but causes memory errors if `N` is too big, due to the `[NxNx(d)]` array I'm creating with `.repeat`  Is there a way to broadcast this?  If I do this:

`data[None,...][mask]`

It doesn't work, but it seems like there has to be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of repeating the data you can make a view with [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
sparseData = np.broadcast_to(data, (data.shape[0],) + data.shape)[mask]
```

However, even easier would be to select the rows of data based on index:

```
I, J = np.nonzero(mask)
sparseData = data[I]  # could also use J
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out an answer based on `np.where(mask)[1]` which is equivalent to your second answer.  Sometimes just writing out the question brings answers to mind.